# Wifi ack failure and retry count

Tags: macbook-pro, wifi, macos

How can I get WiFi ack failure count, retry count and multiple retry count for on Mac ?

Comment: Have you checked into Network Utility?

Comment: Yes, I did. I found network related statistics but not the WiFi ack failure count.